# NameError when attempting to auto increment field with python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, nameerror

I am getting the following error when trying to run my code and I am not sure why:

```
NameError: global name 'rec' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
field = "id_num"
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1 
    pInterval = 1 
    if (rec == 0):
        rec = pStart
    else:
        rec = rec + pInterval
    return rec

incrementCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(IDHex)
for row in incrementCursor:
    row.setValue(field, str(autoIncrement()))
    incrementCursor.updateRow(row)

del incrementCursor
```

Comment: How/where are you running this script?

Comment: I was successfully running this block of code within a Python stand-alone script.  I changed a couple things within the script (but, nothing in this block of code other than the input table) and now am getting the error message.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. Using IDLE, at the moment the code snippet that you have presented would not work up to where you are stuck because, for example, you have not imported ArcPy at its beginning. We need you to make sure you present all parts needed to show us where you are stuck.

Comment: @mmoore you say you changed a couple of things and now the script that was working is no longer working.  Please tell us what you changed

Comment: Have you tried just running the snippet you've included above?  When I run that from the python window in ArcMap it works fine